# excel vba countifs formula referencing a changing worksheet name

Tags: excel, vba

New member and new to VBA. Looking forward to learning as much as possible.

Right now I and trying to use the countifs formula to count the number of occurrences in a column on a different worksheet. Unfortunately it is for a weekly report and when I open it the worksheet name is different every week.

Here is the portion that I am having trouble with:

```
Range("E29").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=COUNTIFS('DynamicNameHere'!C,""failed to upgrade"")"
    Range("E30").Select
```

When I put the specific worksheet name in the code works perfectly fine. I tried looking up how to use the worksheet code name but haven't been successful.
Is there a way to specify the changing worksheet name without having to reference it by its actual name?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you do not need to select the cell to use it.

Second you would quote out the parts that are vba:

```
    Range("E29").FormulaR1C1 = _
     "=COUNTIFS('" & Sheets(2).Name & "'!C,""failed to upgrade"")"
```

Comment: Let me add more details to specify in greater detail.

When I receive the file it has 1 worksheet with a custom name on it. When I run the whole code it adds a new worksheet named sheet1 with a pivot table and text is certain cells. "E29" is on sheet1 and that's where I want the result of the countifs formula. The formula itself is referencing a data in the original custom named worksheet. How can I set up code so when I run the code in future workbooks it will reference the changed worksheet name and provide the updated results without having to give the specific worksheet name every time?

Comment: @GCG is it the first worksheet in the workbook?  You can use `Sheets(1).Name`

Comment: Range("E29").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=COUNTIFS('Sheets(1).Name'!C,""failed to upgrade"")"
        Range("E30").Select

When I try this it opens up an update values window

Comment: @GCG see edit, you need to quote out the vba from the worksheet formula.

Comment: corrected. now when I run the code it gives me 0 as the total because it is reference the new "sheet1" that gets added when running the rest of the code. When I look in the VBE it says Sheet1 (altered name) and Sheet2 (Sheet1). I take that as the code name of the original worksheet is sheet 1 and the added sheet 1 is sheet 2

Comment: @GCG Then is the sheet you want to reference the second sheet?

Comment: @GCG when I say the second sheet I mean looking at the tabs at the bottom is it the second in order from left to right?

Comment: @GCG please mark as correct by clicking on the green check mark by the answer.  It is something only you can do.